# fail to open an outgoing connection (socket) on openshift

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration, openshift

I'm writing a small application to check the function and configuration of several spring features on openshift. you can find the code here: https://github.com/Laures/openshift-spring-testapp

currently i try to test spring-integrations tcp/ip support because openshift has some strict limitations on the ability to bind to ports. the server socket part was simple: pick an allowed port and use the internal server ip (not localhost).

I'm failing at the client side part. i want to open a tcp connection using my public dns entry to connect to my server. as far as i can tell (stacktrace below) my application is unable to open a local socket for the outgoing connection to my server.

```
17:41:36.309 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - Opening new socket connection to springtest-laures.rhcloud.com:4444
17:41:36.317 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.createSocket(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:89) ~[spring-integration-ip-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:63) ~[spring-integration-ip-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[spring-integration-ip-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:116) ~[spring-integration-ip-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:203) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:306) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260) [spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.sendMessage(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.openshift.test.socket.SocketClient.sendMessage(SocketClient.java:24) [SocketClient.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_19]
```

**EDIT 1**

it looks like openshift only allows even outgoing connections to use the internal ip.
I looked into the spring-integration code and there is no way to set the local interface for client connections. and even if there was one the `javax.net.SocketFactory` has no method to get a socket just with the target host/port and the local host.

so for now the question is down to:

**how do i open a client socket to an remote address using a specific local ip as the source**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SocketFactory` [has a couple of `createSocket` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html) that provide a mechanism to specify the local interface. Spring Integration doesn't directly use those methods. However, you can provide a custom `TcpSocketFactorySupport` (based on `DefaultTcpNetSocketFactorySupport`) that wraps the default socket factory and delegates the call to `createSocket(host, port)` to one of the other methods.

Also feel free to open up an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution would help me. but so far i tested several way to create a java.net.Socket for an outgoing connection, so far without success:
`new Socket(host, port, InetAddress.getByName("openshift_private_ip"), 0);` and `createSocket(SocketFactory.getDefault().host, port, InetAddress.getByName("openshift_private_ip"), 0);` as soon as i get ONE working socket i'm probably done

Comment: I think the problem is using port #0. Unfortunately, it does not appear that `SocketFactory` has an option to open a socket using a specific interface, but *any ethereal local port*. How do you select a port to listen on on the server side? Does openshift provide an API to determine which ports are available? If so, you'd need to use it; otherwise, I don't see how you can guess at what ethereal ports are available.